# IN SQL checking if versioned row updated

Tags: mysql, sql

In my mysql database, I have a table, lets call statuses. That table has a creative_id and everytime the status changes for the creative, we record a new row, and change is_current on the old one to 0, and the new one to 1.

I want to query how many have had a status change greater than 90 days, after having the status changed to "audited". So the query below is what ive started, but the problem is that what if something changed in less than 90 days, but over a multitude of changes the end result is greater than 90 days. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM creative_status_version csv
INNER JOIN creative_status_version csv2 
ON csv.creative_id = csv2.creative_id
AND DATEDIFF(day, csv2.last_modified_time, csv.last_modified_time) > 90
WHERE csv.audit_status = 'audited'
AND csv.is_current = 0
AND csv2.audit_status = 'rejected'
AND csv2.is_current = 1
```

Example:

```
|creative_id| audit_status| is_current| last_modified_time |
|1          |audited      | 0         | 1-1-2017           |
|1          |rejecected   | 1         | 5-1-2017           |
|2          |audited      | 0         | 1-1-2017           |
|2          |pending      | 0         | 2-1-2017           |
|2          |rejected     | 1         | 5-1-2017           |
|3          |audited      | 1         | 1-1-2017           |
|4          |rejected     | 1         | 5-1-2017           |
```

Because the only result that went from audited -> anything else... after a time span of 90 days is the creative with id =1, the result would be:

```
|Count(*)|
|1       |
```

Comment: I'm sory, but I do not understand your question. Pls provide some sample data, the expected output, and the output provided by your query. Pls choose your sample data to demonstrate the issue you are trying to describe.

Comment: So essentially, What you want is to query all status changes that are or have been greater than 90 days. That would be quite hard in pure SQL and I'd recommend adding a flag and amending it server side if it has ever been  over 90 days

Comment: That's right Joshua, but I don't have that option for org burocracy reasons

Comment: @Shadow I edited to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

The logic I follow is:

1. Obtain all audited records
2. For the same creative id and audited record get the minimum date where status is not audited and the date is greater than the audited date
3. Count if the time difference is >90 days

   ```
   Select count(*) from
       (select csv.creative_id, csv.last_modified_time
       FROM creative_status_version csv
       INNER JOIN creative_status_version csv2 ON csv.creative_id = csv2.creative_id
       WHERE csv.audit_status = 'audited'
       AND csv2.audit_status <> 'audited'
       AND csv2.last_modified_time>csv.last_modified_time
       GROUP BY csv.creative_id, csv.last_modified_time
       HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, csv.last_modified_time, min(csv2.last_modified_time)) > 90) t
   ```

If you can have more than one audited record percreative id and you want only to count the difference between the latest of them and the earliest non-audit one, thenyou need to have a subquery in place of `creative_status_version csv` that returns the max date per creative id where status is audited.